# Getting realtime output using Python Subprocess and autoit

Tags: python, autoit

I am trying to approach to a process from my python script.
I am trying to get a value that i can get from only autoit, i want it from specific process

```
process2 = subprocess.Popen([dpa_path], stdin = subprocess.PIPE,stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

#I tried some ways, and none of them worked. examples:
process2.stdout.read(int(process2.stdin.write(str(Auto.ControlCommand("", "", "TBitBtn2" ,"IsVisible", "")))
```

or

```
process2.stdout.read(Auto.ControlCommand("", "", "TBitBtn2" ,"IsVisible", ""))
```

for autoit I am using

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
Auto = Dispatch("AutoItX3.Control")
```

and for the process I am using

```
import subprocess
```

how can i get the value that is retuned from the Auto.ControlCommand?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, AFAIK there is no direct way to directly get the returned value. Depending on what you need to do with the returned value you can choose from some options.

1. Run AutoIt script from SciTE-Lite editor (bundled with AutoIt). Go for Tools -> Go. That way, anything you *print*, will be printed in internal console of SciTE. Use `ConsoleWrite("string")`
2. Pop a MsgBox like this:

[image: AutoIt MsgBox]

For more detailed info on how to use MsgBox refer to AutoIt doc: https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MsgBox.htm

Let me know if this fixes your problem.